# VS2015 install keeps hanging

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install vs2015 CTP5 on a fully updated Windows 8.1 and the install keeps hanging (for an hour or so) on the LocalESPCui for en-us Dev12 step.

I'm using the .iso that is mounted with PowerISO, how can I make it to finish the install?

Answer (score 1):

The install never worked and always kept hanging on the same point.

Tried the following things:

- Run the .msi for the .. package -> didn't work
- Remove VS2013 which was installed at the time -> didn't work
- Tried downloading the .iso from the msdn library -> didn't work
- Tried the web installer -> didn't work
- Tried removing all the registry keys linked to Visual Studio -> didn't work
- Reinstalled Windows 8.1 and ran the web installer -> **Successful**

It nows runs without problems.

Comment: Not the answer I was after!

Answer (score 0):

If the installer is asking you to provide the location of the package, you can download the ISO, mount it (using WinCDEmu or similar) and then point the installer to `<drive>:\packages\EspC`. This allowed the installation to continue in my case (VS2015 Update 3).