# Fix VS2015 install?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After a bad install VS2015 hangs in repair or uninstall. How do I troubleshoot or fix?

I don't want to reinstall Windows as per this post: [VS2015 install keeps hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514093/vs2015-install-keeps-hanging)

I have Windows 7 64-bit.

This is where it hangs on uninstall (and remains stuck even after I hit cancel):
[image]

I have left it running for hours for both Repair and Uninstall!

Answer (score 0):

I disabled `system restore`, didn't mount the ISO and hit cancel when it prompted me for installer locations. This seemed to work for uninstalling. (It's unclear if a re-install will work).